How to specify the naming format of PVCs when using Statefulset in Kubernetes?
The following is the Statefulset yaml.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  serviceName: mongo
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo

( skip )

  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data-volume
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi

Due to the use of the volumeClaimTemplates, the PVC name must be:
data-volume-mongodb-0
data-volume-mongodb-1
data-volume-mongodb-2

However, the action of creating PVCs is not within my control. The PVC naming format provided by the other party is as follows:
mongodb-0-pvc
mongodb-1-pvc
mongodb-2-pvc

Therefore, I need to follow their naming format while continuing to use the volumeClaimTemplates.
How should I modify it?

You cannot change that, the PVC name of stateful set will always be <statefulset name>-<ordinal index> , so it will always end with the ordinal.

What's different between your volumeClaimTemplates: and the other PVCs?  Can you make your StatefulSet have the right settings and remove the other PVCs?

My PVCs is no different from other's. However, based on the discussion, the PVCs can only be created by others. I have reported that the PVCs name can only end with the ordinal, so no changing is needed on my end. Thank you very much for everyone's comments.

@Jason, For better community reach, can you please post your comment as an answer.

Thanks for everyone's comments. The PVCs name can only end with the ordinal, so no changing is needed.
